# Does not name a type for Grades class

Tags: c++

Here is my student. h class. It giives me Grades does not name a type error. Can you help me?

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
#include "Grades.h"
using std::string;
class Student
{
public:
    Grades *grade;
    Student();
    Student(int, string);
    string  studentName;
    int     studentID;
    void displayStudent();


protected:
private:

};

#endif
```

Comment: Do you have an `#include "student.h"` line in Grades.h? Also, for which .cpp file does this compile error appear?

Comment: That doesn't look like it even does anything.  It just declares methods and fields

Comment: What are you asking?  This is not at all clear.

Comment: yes Ihave #include"student.h" in grades.h

Comment: my program gives me Grades does not name a type error. It is probably student class does not realize grades class. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might trimmed down, but it looks like you've got a circular reference error: Student refers to Grades, and Grades refers to Student (maybe?).

Instead of `#include "Grades.h"`, just add a forward reference to the class: `class Grades;` and see if that works. Alternately, do the equivalent in Student.h.

Normally, if you have two classes that have to refer to each other, you'd just use a forward reference in the .h file and put the `#include` in the .cpp. Or get rid of the cyclical reference...

Comment: Thanks it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a *circular reference* where two of your header files include each other. This is typically inducing a compile error unless it's solved with some tricks.

In your case you don't even need to cross-include the two header files. Forward-declaring is enough in most cases:

```
class Grades;
```

instead of

```
#include "Grades.h"
```

should solve this. You can do this with all types in your header file unless you either inherit from them or have them as non-pointer / non-reference members in your class. Even for function arguments you don't need to include them.